# Upload a text file with Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I want to create an application where the user after authentication can upload a file(txt/xml etc.) using the Azure Mobile Services and after that he can download only those files which were uploaded by himself.

I've watched a lot of tutorials (including this one: [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services/Windows-Phone-Authenticate-and-Authorize-users-with-Server-Scripts-in-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services) ) but in this case they simply inserts a row to a database table. I want basically the same thing, just with files. How can I do that?

I'm really new to this, so I'm just guessing, but should I upload the files to Blob Storage, and store a link in the database pointing to that file? I'm searching for the best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct!
You would be limited in size if you tried to store the text file as a field in the database.
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-upload-data-blob-storage/
Shows how to do what you want to do but with images.
You would want to change the image stream to a text stream here:

```
 // Get the new image as a stream.
using (var fileStream = await media.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    ...
}
```

And use the Stream classes instead to open the file stream:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.stream(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I've tried to implement this, but I ran to an error: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441250/upload-text-file-to-azure-blob-storage-returns-internal-server-error) Do you know why this error occurs?