# Upload text file to Azure blob Storage returns Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I want to create an application, where the user can upload a text file to the Azure Blob Storage. I was using this example, but even this can't work for me: [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-upload-data-blob-storage/#install-storage-client)

I modified a little bit for my thing:

```
[DataContract]
public class WorkoutItem
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "containerName")]
    public string ContainerName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resourceName")]
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sasQueryString")]
    public string SasQueryString { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "filePath")]
    public string Filepath { get; set; }
}
```

I want to upload a txt file, here is the method:

```
private async void InsertWorkoutItem(string localpath)
    {
        try
        {
            item = new WorkoutItem();
            string errorString = string.Empty;

            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile(
                localpath + ".txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                item.ContainerName = "workoutitemfiles";
                item.ResourceName = localpath + ".txt";
            }

            await workouttable.InsertAsync(item); //exception thrown here

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.SasQueryString))
            {
                StorageCredentials cred = new StorageCredentials(item.SasQueryString);
                var fileUri = new Uri(item.Filepath);

                CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(
                    string.Format("https://{0}/{1}", fileUri.Host, item.ContainerName)), cred);

                CloudBlockBlob blobFromSASCredential = container.GetBlockBlobReference(item.ResourceName);
                await blobFromSASCredential.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

Exception details:

```
    {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: Error: Internal Server Error
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<RequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<>c__DisplayClass10.<<InsertAsync>b__f>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<TransformHttpException>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<InsertAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<TransformHttpException>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<InsertAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<InsertAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at GPS_BLRM67.ViewModel.MainViewModel.<InsertWorkoutItem>d__c.MoveNext()}
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<RequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<>c__DisplayClass10.<<InsertAsync>b__f>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<TransformHttpException>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<InsertAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<TransformHttpException>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<InsertAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1.<InsertAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at GPS_BLRM67.ViewModel.MainViewModel.<InsertWorkoutItem>d__c.MoveNext()
```

Error on server-side:

```
Error in script '/table/WorkoutItem.insert.js'. Error: {"message":"The provided settings {\"blobendpoint\":\"http://undefined.blob.core.windows.net/\",\"tableendpoint\":\"http://undefined.blob.core.windows.net/\",\"queueendpoint\":\"http://undefined.blob.core.windows.net/\"} are not complete."}
```

Here is the server-side insert script:

```
    var azure = require('azure');
var qs = require('querystring');
var appSettings = require('mobileservice-config').appSettings;

function insert(item, user, request) {
    // Get storage account settings from app settings. 
    var accountName = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
    var accountKey = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY;
    var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';

    if ((typeof item.containerName !== "undefined") && (
    item.containerName !== null)) {
        // Set the BLOB store container name on the item, which must be lowercase.
        item.containerName = item.containerName.toLowerCase();

        // If it does not already exist, create the container 
        // with public read access for blobs.        
        var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);
        blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(item.containerName, {
            publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
        }, function(error) {
            if (!error) {

                // Provide write access to the container for the next 5 mins.        
                var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                    AccessPolicy: {
                        Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
                        Expiry: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
                    }
                };

                // Generate the upload URL with SAS for the new image.
                var sasQueryUrl = 
                blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(item.containerName, 
                item.resourceName, sharedAccessPolicy);

                // Set the query string.
                item.sasQueryString = qs.stringify(sasQueryUrl.queryString);

                // Set the full path on the new new item, 
                // which is used for data binding on the client. 
                item.filePath = sasQueryUrl.baseUrl + sasQueryUrl.path;

            } else {
                console.error(error);
            }
            request.execute();
            item.userId=user.userId;
        });
    } else {
        request.execute();
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I've read in another thread that maybe the Windows Azure Storage reference is not added to the project, but that's not the problem for me.

Comment: Looking at the error message I see "http://undefined.blob.core.windows.net". It looks like maybe your accountName var is undefined. Could you try printing that and checking the output?

Comment: Yes I did, that was the case. Thanks for the help though, now it is working as it should.

Comment: @fzl how did you solve this, I think I have the same problem these two lines are not working for me. var appSettings = require('mobileservice-config').appSettings;
    var accountName = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;

Comment: @erotavlas For me, the problem was a badly configured mobile service. I went to my Azure management portal, selected the propriate mobile service you created for your application, go to Configure tab, and write your credentials to the app settings. An item contains of a name and its value. At the left side, you need to give the name which you can refer to in the script, in our case its STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME. Next to it, you should write the value you want this item to get. Hope you can make it work with this.